# Osgi app - Missing Bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.http" in Equinox 3.9

Tags: eclipse, osgi

I'm trying to develop a OSGi app based on the tutorial in below link.

http://bryanhunt.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/osgi-as-a-web-application-server/

In that tutorial, Launch configuration step, it is mentioned like to check the following bundles - **org.eclipse.equinox.http**.

I'm using Eclipse kepler with Equinox 3.9 as target platform. In the Run Configuration,I could not find **org.eclipse.equinox.http**.

Can Anyone suggest me ,How to include that bundle in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information about that bundle (and related ones) here:

http://eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_equinox.php

Eclipse provides a download with all bundles that are part of the Equinox project:

http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-KeplerSR2-201402211700/index.php

Answer (score 0):

The bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http is not included within the default Eclipse installation. The easiest way is to import the [Eclipse Equinox HTTP team project set file](http://eclipse.org/equinox/server/downloads/equinoxhttp-anon.psf) ([description](http://eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_equinox.php)) and to import the project set to your Eclipse workspace, see [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Project_Set_File) how to import such files.